# WordPress site hacked, recovered but Google still has hacked page description

Tags: wordpress, security, hacking, malware, virus

My website got hacked recently and recovered it. It was populating casino ads on my website. There were virtually made URLs where casino pages were displayed.

I suspected the code came through a plugin and by taking help from the communities I was able to recover my website. But Google still has the pages (a lot of them) indexed. I resubmitted a request to crawl the full site a few weeks back, but still those are there. A site: search with casino keyword still displays the URLs. I am worried that my website's reputation will go down. Already a fall in traffic is noticeable.

I have removed everything from the database tables, disavowed links etc. But there are lots of links and I really do not want the contents to be removed from Google. To make you clear, the contents of the pages are there, the bug only changed the description and the title of the pages.

Comment: Unfortunately it takes time. You just gotta wait it out.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you will want to make sure your site does not exist in any of the blacklists. You can use http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx to check. There is information on how to get your site removed if you follow the links.